# Supplying more power to USB device over a USB connection to PC

Tags: usb, power-supply, android, adb

I have multiple Android devices that I need to be connected to a PC over USB at all times (using a powered USB hub or connected directly to one of the USB ports on the PC)

Now the Android devices I need to connect all have varying power requirements ranging from 5V 1A, 5V 2A to 5V 3A and possibly more. The USB ports on the PC can only supply 5V 0.5A if I'm not wrong and even with powered USB hubs that I could find on the market, the maximum a single USB port can output is 5V 1.5A which is not enough for the Android device to work properly (although it does work)

All these Android devices come with their own power bricks that output the right amount of power but they're all powered via USB so if I connect each device to its respective power brick, I can't connect them to the PC over USB (I know about ADB over Wi-Fi but I don't want that because a USB connection is more reliable)

Is there a way around this problem where I can supply the devices the power they need over USB while also having them connected to a PC over USB?

Maybe a way to increase the power output of a PC's USB hub? Maybe a specialized powered USB hub available in the market? Maybe a cable with two USB A plugs and a micro USB plug where one of the A plugs connects to a power brick for power and the other connects to the PC for data and the micro USB plug connects to the Android device?

Comment: "Maybe a way to increase the power output of a PC's USB hub?" - No; This does not exist.  Your power limitations are a result of USB 3.2 Gen 1.  What you need is probably at least USB 3.2 GEN 2

Comment: @Ramhound with USB 3.2 gen 2 what's the maximum current you can get from a single USB port? I looked online but I'm not sure I can find the right data.

Comment: Use *separate* powered USB hubs for each high-current device, i.e., each powered hub connected to one central hub. Not the greatest solution, because each hub adds length to the cable, but it might serve your purpose.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik that's what I'm planning to do but even the powered USB hubs I found can only output 1.5 Amps max on a port. I saw a couple of Y shaped USB cables with 2 male and one female port. They claim to double the power so 1.5x2 but I've not used them yet since they're hard to find

Comment: You will have to go with USB hubs, but you can of course have a usb hub to split to multiple hubs, then have the next hubs with power to actually provide the power.

Comment: Also, please understand... just because you want something to be possible, doesn't mean the limitations suddenly vanish because you want to. Learn what the limits are, and find a solution that works for you that works within the confines of the limits.

Comment: @LPChip "a usb hub to split to multiple hubs". I didn't quite understand that. Do you have an example? Also, regarding your second comment, I am simply asking to see if a solution exists. However, since device farms exist, I figured maybe other people ran into the same problem and figured something out.

Comment: computer usb goes to hub to have more usb devices, each device gets a dedicated usb hub with power so the power is not drawn from the usb host, everything is connected. So: `pc` -> `enough hubs so you have enough usb ports` -> `a hub per phone, powered` -> `phone`. So lets say you have 5 phones, and your pc has just 2 usb ports. You get 1 4 port usb hub, because you can actually use the other usb port from the pc. Then, as you have 5 phones, you need 5 usb hubs that are also powered. They can have just 2 ports but likely the minimum is 4 ports.

Comment: You can buy 1 powered usb hub first and see how many ports it can actually charge before the phones stop getting enough charge from the usb ports and stop charging...

Comment: Are you sure you have such high power requirements? For regular Android devices such power requirements are for fast charging only. But if you have devices connected 24/7 the power requirement is much smaller as the devices do not charge at all or only using very slow charging for charging from 90 to 100%. I would recommend to use a active powered USB hub and check it it works (1-3 devices per hub).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not powering devices with a battery. I'm powering Android TV devices with no battery and they have varying power requirements depending on the device

Comment: @Vinayak Then I assume the USB connector is non-standard, because only via USB-C are 3A at 5V allowed. All the older connectors are limited to 1.5A or less according to the USB standard.

Comment: No, they're standard micro USB connectors. For example, various Amazon FireTV devices [have different power requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Fire_TV#Models). The pendant model uses 5.2V at 1.8A